# Convert List<> to Task<List<>>

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to convert a list from `List<>` to `Task<List<>>` ? I know `Task<List<>>` to `List<>` but I don't know to other direction.

Thanks,

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do? It matters. Do you want to create a "finished" task that contains a `List<>` payload? `Task.FromResult(someList)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `Task.FromResult(* your List<> here *)`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `Task.FromResult(list)`? Where `list` is the variable storing reference to your Collection.